# I Have a Button in a UserControl which should call a method in the main window

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls

i would like to trigger a method in the main Windows through a Button in a user Controll (my sidebar). How can i do this?

Comment: your usercontrol should emit a event which your main window can subscribe to. How to archive this, idk since im not working with wpf.

Comment: Easiest is to implement an ICommand on your main window class and bind the Button.Command property to it. [Commanding Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/commanding-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8).

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by calling the following inside of your buttons void.

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Window parentWindow = Window.GetWindow(this);
    parentWindow.Foo() // Foo is your Functions name inside of the main window.
}
```

If that doesn't work you could do is to cast the result of Window.GetWindow(this) to MainWindow, as seen below

```
MainWindow parentWindow = (MainWindow)  Window.GetWindow(this);
parentWindow.Foo();
```

However it's a really bad class design as now your user control depends on being embedded in a specific window.

What you should do instead, is to add an event to the user control which the parent control can subscribe to.

```
public event EventHandler myEventHandler;

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var handler = myEventHandler;
    if (handler != null) handler(this, EventArgs.Empty);
}
```

You may aswell use a different event handler than what's present here to fit your needs.